# How to create dynamic radio button

Tags: jquery

I am tring to create a form with MVC 4 and jquery. When the user clicks on a button: 
-a input text appears as a "question title"
-Two options of radio button with  input text for the user adds the value of the "question answer"
-The user is allowed to add more option, i.e, add more radio button.

I've read some articles and some posts here about create radio button dynamically  but I did not find something specific about creating dynamic radio button ( user creates everything) . I want to know how I could deal with ID for these questions and values of the radio button and how to retrieve this values after the form is created.

Please no code is needed, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when a user add a new entry, you put the data in your database, then update your view with the new list.

Check out $.ajax, HTTP PUT